# Evans proof of smoothness of solutions to the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, heat-equation

This is Theorem 8 in Section 2.3 of Evans:

**Theorem.** Suppose $u \in C_{1}^{2}(U_{T})$ solves the heat equation in $U_{T}$. Then $u \in C^{\infty}(U_{T})$.

Here, $U_{T} := U \times (0,T]$. In his proof, he obtains a representation

$$u(x,t) = \int\int_{C} \Phi(x-y,t-s)[(\zeta_{s}(y,s) - \Delta \zeta(y,s))u(y,s) - 2D\zeta(y,s)\cdot Du(y,s)]\;dyds$$

where $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution, $C$ is a cylinder of radius $r$ and height $r^2$ whose top center point is some chosen $(x_{0},t_{0}) \in U_{T}$, $C'$ and $C''$ are similar cylinders with radii $3r/4$ and $r/2$, resp., and $(x,t) \in C''$. Evans integrates the last term by parts:

$$-\int\int_{C} 2\Phi(x-y,t-s) D\zeta(y,s) \cdot Du(y,s)\;dyds = \int\int_{C} [2D_{y}\Phi(x-y,t-s)\cdot D\zeta(y,s)]u(y,s)\;dyds$$

I really don't see how he obtains this. There are three factors in the integrand, so I always end up with some $\Delta \zeta(y,s)$ term which doesn't vanish.

Comment: Your second equation isn't what Evans is claiming, and in fact we do want a $\Delta \zeta$ term. Notice the change in sign of the $\Delta \zeta$ term between your first equation and (37) in Evans.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that D(ΦDζ∙u)=DΦDζ∙u+ΦΔζ∙u+ΦDζ∙Du, we get 
$ \iint_{\partial C}ΦDζ\cdot u \cdot ν dS = \iint_{C}D_y ΦDζ\cdot u dyds 
+ \iint_{C}Φ\Deltaζ\cdot u dyds + \iint_{C}ΦDζ\cdot Du dyds
$, 
and the LHS vanishes because that $Dζ=0$ for $ζ≡0$ near the parabolic boundary of C . So 
$ \iint_{C}-2ΦDζ\cdot Du dyds=\iint_{C}2D_y ΦDζ\cdot u dyds 
+ \iint_{C}2Φ\Deltaζ\cdot u dyds 
$, 
and we get what exactly we want. :-)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different approach. Note that

$$\langle \nabla \zeta, \nabla (\phi u) \rangle = u \langle \nabla \zeta, \nabla \phi \rangle + \phi \langle \nabla \zeta, \nabla u \rangle$$
so that
$$- \phi \langle \nabla \xi, \nabla u \rangle = u \langle \nabla \zeta, \nabla \phi \rangle - \langle \nabla \zeta, \nabla (\phi u) \rangle.$$

Integrating over $C$, using integration by parts and the fact that $\nabla \zeta$ vanishes on $\partial C$, we obtain

\begin{align}
\iint_C - \phi \langle \nabla \xi, \nabla u \rangle dyds &= \iint_C u \langle \nabla \zeta, \nabla \phi \rangle - \langle \nabla \zeta, \nabla (\phi u) \rangle dyds \\
&= \iint_C u \langle \nabla \zeta, \nabla \phi \rangle+ 2 \phi u \Delta \zeta dyds.
\end{align}

Plugging this in to the expression for $u(x, t)$ gives the desired result.